# Grails not finding view for controller

Tags: grails, model-view-controller, gsp

I have the following Grails 2.3.6 app structure (besides the normal/default Grails structure):

```
myapp/
    grails-app/
        controllers/
            fizzbuzz/
                SomeUserController.groovy
        views/
            someUser/
                someUser.gsp
```

In `SomeController`:

```
class SomeController {
    def index() {
        // Do a bunch of stuff

        render(
            view: "someUser",
            model: [
                someModel: someModel,
                anotherModel: anotherModel
            ]
        )
    }
}
```

When I run `grails run-app` and open a browser to

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp/fizzbuzz/someUser
```

Grails serves back my custom 404 Not Found page. **What's going on, and what can I do to fix it?**

Comment: I dont think you need /fizzbuzz

Comment: Include the controller code in your question as well. Based on what you have there I would assume you have a method def `someUser()` in your controller, but that's an assumption.

Comment: http://localhost:8080/myapp/someUser/show is the correct URL considering there is an action show inside the controller and show.gsp exists inside someUser folder.

Comment: Thanks @JoshuaMoore and Shashank (+1 both) - please see my update which includes the controller code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several things wrong with what is described in the question.

You have a controller at `grails-app/controllers/fizzbuzz/SomeUserController.groovy` and then show code for `SomeController`.  The class name and the file name should match each other.  You should either rename `SomeUserController.groovy` to `SomeController.groovy` or rename the class from `SomeController` to `SomeUserController`.  Note that the directory where your view is stored needs to be kept in sync with that.  If the controller is `SomeController` then the views go in `grails-app/views/some/`.  If the controller is `SomeUserController` then the views go in `grails-app/views/someUser/`.

The url you show is `http://localhost:8080/myapp/fizzbuzz/someUser`.  Unless you have some special mappings in `UrlMappings.groovy` to support that, that won't work.  You probably want `http://localhost:8080/myapp/someUser` if the controller is `SomeUserController` or `http://localhost:8080/myapp/some` if the controller is `SomeController`.

Comment: See the project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/fizzbuzz.  If you run that and send a request to http://localhost:8080/fizzbuzz/someUser you will see the view is rendered.